# Необычная flip card без возврата в обратную сторону при отводе мыши

Tags: css, css-animation

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть такой пример flip анимации карточки https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp

Логика её - при событии hover она поворачивается вправо на 180 градусов и появляется её "обратная" сторона (бэк), т.е. второй div слой, а при отводе мыши возвращается обратно налево на 180 градусов к первому слою (фронту).

Вопрос - можно ли как-то сделать на кейфреймах, чтобы при отводе мыши возврат к исходному положению был не влево, а вправо, как бы проворачивайся на 360 градусов?

https://codepen.io/PollyCatZ/pen/GRGbPpw - вот тут почти добился того, что нужно, но не до конца, при отводе мыши второй слой пропадает и проворачивается дальше право первый слой.

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px; 
}

.flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;  
    animation-name: out;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
}


.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;   
    animation-name: in;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}


.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}


.flip-card-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes in {
  0%{
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  
  100%{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes out {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  
  99% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```